# OWIN and Global.asax.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, global-asax, simple-injector

I use in my project Owin and Katana for OAuth authorization. And all work good but in global.asax.cs file I have some code for IOC container:

```
Bootstrapper.IncludingOnly.Assembly(Assembly.Load("Dashboard.Rest")).With.SimpleInjector().With.ServiceLocator().Start();
            Container container = Bootstrapper.Container as Container;
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

I added this code in **Startup.cs** file but after it I catch next exception:

> An exception of type
>   'Bootstrap.Extensions.Containers.NoContainerException' occurred in
>   Bootstrapper.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to continue. The container has not been
>   initialized.

and if I call someone api methods I catch next exception:

> Unable to continue. The container has not been initialized.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Bootstrap.Extensions.Containers.NoContainerException: Unable to
>   continue. The container has not been initialized.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 21:         public Startup() Line 22:         { Line 23:
>   Bootstrapper.IncludingOnly.Assembly(Assembly.Load("Dashboard.Rest")).With.SimpleInjector().With.ServiceLocator().Start();
>   Line 24:             Container container = Bootstrapper.Container as
>   Container; Line 25:
>   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new
>   SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

I don't know how to fix it. Help me please. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I have some SimpleInjectorRegisterTypes class for connect my interfaces and services:

```
 public class SimpleInjectorRegisterTypes : ISimpleInjectorRegistration
    {
        public void Register(Container container)

            container.RegisterSingle<IApplication, ApplicationService>();      
        }
    }
```

And I have service where I write logic for API.

And in my controllers I create constructor for call my method with help interfaces:

```
 public class ApplicationController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IApplication _application;

        public ApplicationController(IApplication application)
        {
            _application = application;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAllApps()
        {
            var apps = _application.GetAllApps();
            return apps == null ? (IHttpActionResult)Ok(new Application()) : Ok(apps);
        }
....
```

Comment: What kind of IoC container are you using?

Comment: @Kamo I updated my question

Comment: Isn't line `Bootstrapper.Container as Container` giving you `null`?

Comment: @Kamo I catch exception on first line Bootstrapper.IncludingOnly.Assembly(Assembly.Load("Dashboard.Rest")).With.SimpleInjector().With.ServiceLocator().Start();

Comment: You are using some kind of bootstrapping library. The code you showcis not part of Simple Injector's API. Which bootstrapping library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this problems. I just use other IOC container [Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/)

Here is an implementation of IDependencyResolver that wraps a Unity container.

```
public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    protected IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
        return new UnityResolver(child);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

    // Other Web API configuration not shown.
}
```

Some controllers with use IoC containers:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private IProductRepository _repository;

    public ProductsController(IProductRepository repository)  
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // Other controller methods not shown.
}
```

[Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

Comment: So basically your solution is to stop using the Bootstrapper library?

Comment: @Steven just now - yes. :)